# VBA program for GIS application

Tags: excel, performance, vba, optimization, gis

I have a table in Excel with X, Y and Z data in columns B, C and D respectively.

I wrote the following program which gives me pairs of points that are a given distance and elevation from each other:

```
Sub Test1()

c3 = 2

For c2 = 2 To 1445

    For c1 = c2 To 1445

        If Abs(Cells(c1, 4) - Cells(c2, 4)) > 50 Then
            If Sqr((Cells(c2, 2) - Cells(c1, 2)) ^ 2 + (Cells(c2, 3) - Cells(c1, 3)) ^ 2) > 0

                    Cells(c3, 8) = Cells(c1, 2)
                    Cells(c3, 9) = Cells(c1, 3)
                    Cells(c3, 10) = Cells(c2, 2)
                    Cells(c3, 11) = Cells(c2, 3)
                    c3 = c3 + 1
            End If
        End If

    Next c1

Next c2
```

The problem is that the program becomes very slow especially for large quantities of points say above 20,000. My aim was to be able to iterate this process for millions of points at a time for a GIS application. How can I decrease the computational time by either A) Optimising my code/algorithm or B) any external means?

Comment: Do you really have to calculate the square root? Maybe you can work with the squared value.

Comment: Also, if you can use a helper columns, you could do those calculations in one pass rather than looping twice.

Comment: What's the point of the inner if statement? I thought Sqr() returned the positive root and so we will only fail that condition if you are comparing the same exact point. Which leads me to another question... Why are you setting an initial value of `c1 = c2` in the inner loop instead of `c1 = c2 + 1`?? Seems like you are doing an extra 1444 checks comparing against the same exact point.

Comment: If you are doing GIS, is straight-line Euclidean distance really appropriate? Large scale, the world isn't a plane. Small scale, road networks force you to depart from straight lines. In any event, 20,000^2 = 400,000,000 -- which is asking a bit much of VBA, especially if that is at the small end of what you are hoping to do. Perhaps something like R (which can interact with Excel in various ways) can do the heavy lifting. As an added bonus there are already written R packages for many standard GIS problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those interested, I had solved this problem a few years ago directly from ArcGIS. [This thread](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/109718/extracting-all-points-within-a-certain-distance-and-height-difference-from-a-ras) shows the question i asked and the answer someone else so kindly provided.